# UIContainer viewcontroller segue within bounds of container

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uicontainerview

I am using a container to present a tableView. The container only covers 1/5 of the screen. When user selected a row I want to push a viewController within the container , but so far the first viewController is presenting fullscreen.

This is what I currently have on my storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@poolHallJunkie Your question is not clear. What I can tell you with your query is you have some problem with your element width setting. Please clarify the question

Answer (score 0):

Use UINavigationController and hide NavigationBar for it.
To do so - select your tableViewController in storyboard and choose Editor -> Embedded in -> Navigation Controller from Xcode menu. Configure navController to hide navBar. In your back button action use

```
navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
```

You should get something like this:

[image]